# Correct answer to a "Multiple choice" Question

Tags: reading, ielts

Read the following paragraph:

> Morning is also great for breaking out the vitamins. Supplement absorption by
> the body is not temporal-dependent, but naturopath Pam Stone notes that the extra
> boost at breakfast helps us get energised for the day ahead. For improved absorption,
> Stone suggests pairing supplements with a food in which they are soluble and steering
> clear of caffeinated beverages. Finally, Stone warns to take care with storage; high
> potency is best for absorption, and warmth and humidity are known to deplete the
> potency of a supplement.

Now, Answer this MCQ:

> Which is NOT mentioned as a way to improve supplement absorption?
>
> **A.** avoiding drinks containing caffeine while taking supplements
>
> **B.** taking supplements at breakfast
>
> **C.** taking supplements with foods that can dissolve them
>
> **D.** storing supplements in a cool, dry environment

I'd written "D" as correct answer, but official IELTS reading answer key says it's "B
". How?

Option "D" is nowhere mentioned in the paragraph, if it seems, then it's not a way to improve supplement absorption.

Comment: The test is misleading—although perhaps that's part of its intent. It would depend on if it's given along with other "trick" tests or not. The misleading part is the statement that "morning is great for breaking out the vitamins," the implication of which that morning is a better time than other times (which is backed up later on). This, despite the fact that it's not actually true on the *specific* criterion of "vitamin absorption." It's almost a form of  underhanded deception that relies on a completely literal interpretation.

Comment: If it's meant to teach "common" comprehension and English usage, it does a poor job.

Comment: @JosanBassford...Sir, you mean what I've interpreted is correct? Option D is correct?

Comment: No, I mean that I understand why they say B is correct. But I don't see the exercise as being a fair one.

Comment: Yeah.. B is there...but see D, it is too!...I've understood D logically, it isn't a way to improve the process given!

Comment: D is "mentioned" by implication, so it's not an answer. (The correct answer is a negative: what is **not** mentioned.) If warm and wet environments *hinder* absorption then, by logic, cold and dry environments *help* absorption. It's not explicitly stated, but it's understood. But this, too, is somewhat peevish. Because it's true that, in one sense, the actual words (or their synonyms) are not mentioned. The test is making some unexplained assumptions.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. Answering comprehension questions is not about the nuts and bolts of the language, but about broader interpretation.

Comment: There's  nothing wrong with the test question. All of the information necessary to select the correct answer is available in the prompt. It's not an EASY question, as it depends on having a fairly extensive vocabulary and appropriately interpreting a bunch of negations and antonyms, but it's not at all wrong or ambiguous, as some test questions we see are.

Comment: You have to throw common sense out of the window and just ***read*** the text. If you don't understand what it is saying, or "why" B is the correct answer (NOT "how") then it's proof that the test is doing its job. The exam is testing comprehension not our opinion or what we think should be the answer.

Comment: I feel like I’m looking at a naked emperor.  Am I the only person who noticed “Supplement absorption by the body is not temporal-dependent, but … *the extra boost **at breakfast*** helps us get energised for the day ahead.”?  This is not a question of “morning” ≠ “breakfast”; the words “**at breakfast**” are right there in the quote.  Why has nobody explained why that doesn’t qualify as a mention of “at breakfast”?  (Maybe I’m just dense.  I don’t understand exactly what “**the extra boost** at breakfast” is referring to.  It seems like something’s missing.)

Answer (score 2):

B Is correct. "Morning is also great for breaking out the vitamins. Supplement absorption by the body is not [temporal-dependent](https://www.italki.com/question/326965)"  means - depending on time. So there is not a relation between the absorption of supplements and time. (eg breakfast time).

D = "Stone warns to take care with storage; high potency is best for absorption, and warmth and humidity are known to deplete the potency of a supplement." (This means storing supplements in a cool, dry environment is crucial to avoid depleting the potency).

Comment: So are you saying that D is indeed correct? Or B as the answer key has it? Please make your answer **explicit.** @Ariana, it does appear that your test is not one of the best.

Comment: @AndrewLeach This test is given by the official British Council IELTS test providers.  This is less test and more confusion!

Comment: @RobynSimpson nailed it. On these kind of advanced tests, watch out for such trickery. Make sure you are laser-focused on the “call of the question” (i.e., what the question is *specifically* asking you for). It wasn’t just what was not mentioned, but what was not mentioned specifically *as a way to improve supplement absorption*. There will typically only be one credited response per question on these kinds of exams, so when two answers both seem correct, think in terms of choosing the *best* answer.